# Print as a joinpoint in aspectJ and expose all joinpoints in a code

Tags: java, aspectj

One question whose answer I have not been able to figure out in whole day of searching.Can print statement in java as

```
system.out.println();
```

be treated as a joinpoint in aspectJ?

Also is there any way of exposing all the available join points in a code.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void * (String) did the trick.
```

Well still stuck with the exposing all the joinpoints in it.

Comment: But you should also include the within() joinpoint because generally the print statement of the aspect are also captured..Which makes the stack overflow..